upload an image to select folder in cloudinary from remix project
Using the docs I'm able to fetch images from Cloudinary to display on the remix website but I am running into 500 (internal server error) when trying to upload an image to the Cloudinary folder.
Here is some code to help understand what I am trying to do.
My admin media page that fetches and uploads images.
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getFiles, uploadFile } from "~/lib/cloudinary";
import File from "~/components/admin/File";
import {
  json,
  unstable_composeUploadHandlers as composeUploadHandlers,
  unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler as createMemoryUploadHandler,
  unstable_parseMultipartFormData as parseMultipartFormData,
  ActionFunction,
  LoaderFunction,
} from "@remix-run/node";
import FileUpload from "~/components/admin/FileUpload";
import LoadMore from "~/components/admin/FileLoadMore";
import FormData from "form-data";
import { convertToFormData } from "~/utils/utils";

interface LoaderData {
  resources: any; 
  next_cursor: any; 
}

interface File {
  asset_id: string;
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const next = url.searchParams.get("next");
  const files = await getFiles(next);
  return files;
};

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  try {
    const uploadHandler = composeUploadHandlers(
      async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
        if (name !== "img") {
          return undefined;
        }
        // Provide a default value for filename when it's undefined
        const filenameStr = filename || "default_filename";
        const formData: FormData = await convertToFormData(data);
        const uploadedImage = await uploadFile(formData, filenameStr);
        return uploadedImage.public_id;
      },
      createMemoryUploadHandler()
    );

    const formData = await parseMultipartFormData(request, uploadHandler);
    const imgSrc = formData.get("img");
    const imgDesc = formData.get("desc");
    const { _action, ...values } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    console.log(values);

    if (!imgSrc) {
      return json({
        error: "something is wrong",
      });
    }
    return json({
      imgSrc,
      imgDesc,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing upload:", error);
    return json({
      error: "Internal Server Error",
    }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


export default function Media() {
  const data = useLoaderData<LoaderData>();
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any>(data.resources);
  const [next, setNext] = useState<any>(data.next_cursor);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="px-4 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 md:px-0">
        Media
      </h1>

      <FileUpload setFiles={setFiles} setNext={setNext} />

      <ul className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-8  px-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-x-6 sm:px-0 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8">
        {files?.map((file: File) => (
          <File key={file.asset_id} file={file} />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <LoadMore setFiles={setFiles} next={next} setNext={setNext} />
    </>
  );
}

My cloudinary untility.
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import FormData from "form-data";
import { promisify } from "util";
import stream from "stream";
import slugify from "~/lib/slugify";

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUDNAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

interface UploadResult {
  public_id: string;
  // Add other properties as needed based on the Cloudinary upload result
}

export function uploadFile(
  data: FormData,
  filename: string
): Promise<UploadResult> {
  console.log(data instanceof FormData); // should log true if data is FormData

  const file = filename.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
  const uploadPromise = new Promise<UploadResult>((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadStream = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        folder: "test folder",
        unique_filename: false,
        use_filename: true,
        public_id: slugify(file),
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        if (result) {
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(new Error("Upload result is undefined"));
        }
      }
    );

    const formDataStream = data.getBuffer();

    pipeline(stream.Readable.from(formDataStream), uploadStream).catch(
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error writing data to stream:", error);
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });

  return uploadPromise;
}

export async function getFiles(next_cursor: string | null = null) {
  const files = await cloudinary.v2.api.resources({
    type: "upload",
    prefix: "test folder",
    direction: "desc",
    max_results: 15,
    next_cursor,
    metadata: true,
    context: true,
  });

  return files;
}

export async function getFile(id: string): Promise<any> {
  const file = await cloudinary.v2.api.resource("test+folder/" + id, {
    colors: true,
    pages: true,
    image_metadata: true,
  });
  return file;
}

export async function updateFile({
  public_id,
  title,
  alt,
}: {
  public_id: string;
  title: string;
  alt: string;
}): Promise<any> {
  console.log(public_id, alt, title);
  const file = await cloudinary.v2.api.update(public_id, {
    context: "caption=" + title + "|alt=" + alt,
  });
  return file;
}

This is my file upload component that I am having trouble figuring out. It is still in JavaScript while I converted the other files to typescript but that shouldn't be the issue.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFetcher } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function FileUpload({ setFiles, setNext }) {
  const fileUpload = useFetcher();
  const uploadFetcher = useFetcher();
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  function handleFileChange(event) {
    const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
    setSelectedFiles(files);
    console.log("Selected Files:", files); // Log selected files
  }

  async function handleUpload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append("img", file);
    });

    // Log FormData entries
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`${key}:`, value);
    }

    try {
      fileUpload.submit(formData, {
        method: "post",
        action: "/admin/media?index",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setError("Failed to upload files. Please try again.");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fileUpload.type === "done") {
      setUploadStatus(fileUpload.type);
    }
  }, [fileUpload]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadStatus === "done") {
      uploadFetcher.load(`/admin/media`);
    }
  }, [uploadStatus]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadStatus === "done") {
      uploadFetcher.load(`/admin/media?index`);
    }
  }, [uploadStatus]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadFetcher.data) {
      setFiles(uploadFetcher.data.resources);
      setNext(uploadFetcher.data.next_cursor);
    }
  }, [uploadFetcher.data]);

  return (
    <div className="my-6 mx-4 flex justify-center rounded-md border-2 border-dashed border-gray-300 pt-5 pb-6 group-hover:bg-slate-300 sm:mx-0 ">
      <form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
        {(fileUpload.state === "submitting" ||
          fileUpload.state === "loading") && (
          <span className="inline-flex items-center justify-center">
            <svg
              className="stroke-4 -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 animate-spin fill-current text-black"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <circle className="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
              <path
                className="opacity-75"
                d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"
              ></path>
            </svg>{" "}
            Uploading...
          </span>
        )}

        <label htmlFor="img" className="">
          <span className="sr-only">Upload a file</span>
          <input
            id="img"
            name="img"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleFileChange}
            className="block w-full text-sm text-slate-500 file:mr-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:bg-violet-50 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:text-indigo-700 hover:file:bg-indigo-100"
            multiple
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        {error && <p className="text-red-500">{error}</p>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

This is my console.
POST http://localhost:3000/admin/media?_data=routes%2Fadmin.media._index 500 (Internal Server Error)
await in fetchData
handleUpload    @   FileUpload.jsx:30
Show 35 more frames
It pertains to this part of the code.
try {
      fileUpload.submit(formData, {
        method: "post",
        action: "/admin/media?",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setError("Failed to upload files. Please try again.");
    }
  }


"500 (internal server error)" is a backend server error, so you will likely need to start there when investigating the issue. Can you [edit] to include the complete error message and accompanying stacktrace? It may shed some light on what when wrong.

@DrewReese I found the issue. I was not formatting my image data correctly to send to Cloudinary. I'll update the code so that others can learn from it.

I ended up using writeAsyncIterableToWritable from @remix-run/node instead of FormData to send uploads. Here are the updated files.
Admin media page.
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getFiles, uploadFile } from "~/lib/cloudinary";
import File from "~/components/admin/File";
import {
  json,
  unstable_composeUploadHandlers as composeUploadHandlers,
  unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler as createMemoryUploadHandler,
  unstable_parseMultipartFormData as parseMultipartFormData,
  ActionFunction,
  LoaderFunction,
} from "@remix-run/node";
import FileUpload from "~/components/admin/FileUpload";
import LoadMore from "~/components/admin/FileLoadMore";

interface LoaderData {
  resources: any; // replace 'any' with the actual type of 'resources'
  next_cursor: any; // replace 'any' with the actual type of 'next_cursor'
}

interface File {
  // Define the properties of 'file' here
  // For example:
  asset_id: string;
  // Add other properties as needed
}

interface UploadedImage {
  public_id: string;
  // Add other properties as needed
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const next = url.searchParams.get("next");
  const files = await getFiles(next);
  return files;
};

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  try {
    const uploadHandler = composeUploadHandlers(
      async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
        console.log(filename);
        const filenameStr = filename || "default_filename";
        if (name !== "img") {
          return undefined;
        }
        const uploadedImage = await uploadFile(data, filenameStr) as UploadedImage;
        console.log(uploadedImage);
        return uploadedImage.public_id;
      },
      createMemoryUploadHandler()
    );

    const formData = await parseMultipartFormData(request, uploadHandler);
    const imgSrc = formData.get("img");
    const imgDesc = formData.get("desc");
    const { _action, ...values } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    console.log(values);

    if (!imgSrc) {
      return json({
        error: "something is wrong",
      });
    }
    return json({
      imgSrc,
      imgDesc,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing upload:", error);
    return json({
      error: "Internal Server Error",
    }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


export default function Media() {
  const data = useLoaderData<LoaderData>();
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any>(data.resources);
  const [next, setNext] = useState<any>(data.next_cursor);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="px-4 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 md:px-0">
        Media
      </h1>

      <FileUpload setFiles={setFiles} setNext={setNext} />

      <ul className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-8  px-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-x-6 sm:px-0 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8">
        {files?.map((file: File) => (
          <File key={file.asset_id} file={file} />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <LoadMore setFiles={setFiles} next={next} setNext={setNext} />
    </>
  );
}

Cloudinary Utility
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import FormData from "form-data";
import { writeAsyncIterableToWritable } from "@remix-run/node";
import slugify from "~/lib/slugify";

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUDNAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

export async function uploadFile(data: FormData | AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>, filename: string) {
  const file = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
  const uploadPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadStream = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        folder: "FolderName",
        unique_filename: false,
        use_filename: true,
        public_id: slugify(file)
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(result);
      }
    );
    await writeAsyncIterableToWritable(data, uploadStream);
  });

  return uploadPromise;
}

export async function getFiles(next_cursor: string | null = null) {
  const files = await cloudinary.v2.api.resources({
    type: "upload",
    prefix: "FolderName",
    direction: "desc",
    max_results: 15,
    next_cursor,
    metadata: true,
    context: true,
  });

  return files;
}

export async function getFile(id: string): Promise<any> {
  const file = await cloudinary.v2.api.resource("FolderName/" + id, {
    colors: true,
    pages: true,
    image_metadata: true,
  });
  return file;
}

export async function updateFile({
  public_id,
  title,
  alt,
}: {
  public_id: string;
  title: string;
  alt: string;
}): Promise<any> {
  console.log(public_id, alt, title);
  const file = await cloudinary.v2.api.update(public_id, {
    context: "caption=" + title + "|alt=" + alt,
  });
  return file;
}

File upload component
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFetcher, useNavigate } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function FileUpload({ setFiles, setNext }) {
  const fileUpload = useFetcher();
  const uploadFetcher = useFetcher();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  function handleFileChange(event) {
    const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
    setSelectedFiles(files);
    console.log("Selected Files:", files); // Log selected files
  }

  async function handleUpload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      if (file instanceof File) {
        formData.append("img", file);
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid file type:", file);
        setError("Invalid file type. Please select a valid file.");
        return;
      }
    });

    // Log FormData entries
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`${key}:`, value);
    }

    try {
      fileUpload.submit(formData, {
        method: "post",
        action: "/admin/media?index",
        encType: "multipart/form-data",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Upload error:", err); // Log the error
      setError("Failed to upload files. Please try again.");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fileUpload.type === "done") {
      setUploadStatus(fileUpload.type);
    }
  }, [fileUpload]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadStatus === "done") {
      uploadFetcher.load(`/admin/media`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate(0); // Refresh the page after a delay
      }, 2000); // 2-second delay
    }
  }, [uploadStatus, navigate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadFetcher.data) {
      setFiles(uploadFetcher.data.resources);
      setNext(uploadFetcher.data.next_cursor);
    }
  }, [uploadFetcher.data]);

  return (
    <div className="my-6 mx-4 flex justify-center rounded-md border-2 border-dashed border-gray-300 pt-5 pb-6 group-hover:bg-slate-300 sm:mx-0 ">
      <form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
        {(fileUpload.state === "submitting" ||
          fileUpload.state === "loading") && (
          <span className="inline-flex items-center justify-center">
            <svg
              className="stroke-4 -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 animate-spin fill-current text-black"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <circle className="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
              <path
                className="opacity-75"
                d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"
              ></path>
            </svg>{" "}
            Uploading...
          </span>
        )}

        <label htmlFor="img" className="">
          <span className="sr-only">Upload a file</span>
          <input
            id="img"
            name="img"
            type="file"
            onChange={handleFileChange}
            className="block w-full text-sm text-slate-500 file:mr-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:bg-violet-50 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:text-indigo-700 hover:file:bg-indigo-100"
            multiple
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        {error && <p className="text-red-500">{error}</p>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

